# How to get least length circuit around rectangles?

Tags: graph

At last competition I was I've been given set of buildings and I needed to create least length length fence around these buildings. Fence may touch build's corners, walls, but may not pass over building and all buildings have to be in one area.

I know that I need to building corners that are at edge of fence's polygon. But I didn't know how to write it for computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain convex hull will be your least-length fence. Just take a set of points that describe the corners of your buildings (assuming your buildings are polygons) and build a convex hull around these points.

[Convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) for a set of points is a classic, basic and very well-researched computational geometry problem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

[Gift wrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) algorithm is very easy to understand and implement.